# How to exit loop when input is nothing

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, integer

I'm trying to work out the average of numbers that the user will input. If the user inputs nothing (as in, no value at all) I want to then calculate the average of all numbers that have been input by the user upto that point. Summing those inputs and finding the average is working well, but I'm getting value errors when trying to break the loop when the user inputs nothing. For the if statement I've tried

`if number == ''` 
First attempt that didn't work, also tried `if number == int("")`

`if len(number) == 0`
This only works for strings

`if Value Error` throws up same error

Full code below

```
sum = 0

while True :
    number = int(input('Please enter the number: '))
    sum += number
    if number == '' :
        break

print(sum//number)
```

Error I'm getting is

> number = int(input('Please enter the number: '))
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:>

Any help much appreciated!

**EDIT:** Now getting closer thanks to the suggestions in that I can get past the problems of no value input but my calculation of average isn't working out.

Trying this code calculates fine but I'm adding the first input twice before I move to the next input

```
total = 0

amount = 0

while True :
    user_input = input('Please enter the number: ')
    try:
        number = int(user_input)
        total = number + number
        amount += 1
    except:
        break
    total += number

print(total/amount)
```

Now I just want to figure out how I can start the addition from the second input instead of the first.

Comment: Welcome! Try defining the input first so: `user_input = input('Your text')`  and convert later by: `number = int(user_input)`. Between the two I would ad the if statement.

Comment: Additional remark: You're overwrting the built-in function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with the name of your variable. It might be a better idea to call your variable `total` or something like that.

Comment: As a side note it's discouraged to use popular builtin functions as variable names i.e. `sum` in this case.  A suggestion would be `sum_` instead.

Comment: Does the error appear when using the print statement in try and except aswell as suggested by: `czromXL`

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0

while True :
    number = input('Please enter the number: '))
    if number == '' :
        break
    sum += int(number)
print(sum//number)
```

try like this

the issue is using int() python try to convert input value to int. So, when its not integer value, python cant convert it. so it raise error. Also you can use Try catch with error and do the break.

Comment: Thanks! It worked but I'm now getting calc erros for the average. I've updated my question to suit

Comment: @RenaissanceMan i think, you get that error when you break the loop in first try. i mean when code start and ask the input, then you not type number so it will break, after that you try to get average. It means you try to divide by 0. thats why error show.

Answer (score 0):

You will always get input as a string, and if the input is not a int then you cant convert it to an int. Try:

```
sum = 0

while True :
    number = input('Please enter the number: ')
    if number == '' :
        break
    sum += int(number)

print(sum//number)
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers dont work since the print statement referse to a string.

```
sum = 0

while True :
    user_input = input('Please enter the number: ')
    try:
        number = int(user_input)
    except:
        break
    sum += number

print(sum//number)
```

including a user_input will use the last int as devisor.

My answer also makes sure the script does not crash when a string is entered.

Comment: Thanks! That did work but I'm now getting calc errors for the average. I've edited and updated my question with new code

Answer (score 0):

The user has to always input something (enter is a character too) for it to end or you will have to give him a time limit.
You can convert character into int after you see it isn't a character or
use try & except.

```
sum = 0
i = 0

while True :
    try:
        number = int(input('Please enter the number: '))
    except ValueError:
        break
    i += 1
    sum += number
try:
    print(sum/number)
except NameError:
    print("User didn't input any number")
```

If you try to convert a character into int it will show ValueError.
So if this Error occurs you can break from the loop.
Also, you are trying to get the average value.
So if a user inputs nothing you get NameError so you can print an Error message.

Answer (score -2):

```py
total = 0
count = 0


while True :
    try:
        new_number = float(input('Please enter the number: '))
        count += 1
        total += new_number
    except:
        break

print(total/count)
```